# Examining an algorithm on a sorted array

Tags: algorithm, big-o, analysis

I have a sorted array of length `n` and I am using linear search to compare my value to every element in the array, then i perform a linear search on the array of size `n/2` and then on a size of `n/4`, `n/8` etc until i do a linear search on an array of length 1. In this case  n is a power of 2, what are the number of comparisons performed?

Not sure exactly if this response is correct but I thought that the number of comparisons would be

> T(2<sup>n</sup>) = (n/2) +(n/4) + ... + 1.

My reasoning for this was because you have to go through every element and then you just keep adding it, but I am still not sure. If someone could walk me through this I would appreciate it

Comment: You use "lineary search" or "binary search"?

Answer (score 4):

The recurrence you have set up in your question is a bit off, since if n is the length of your input, then you wouldn't denote the length of the input by 2<sup>n</sup>.  Instead, you'd write it as n = 2<sup>k</sup> for some choice of k.  Once you have this, then you can do the math like this:

- The size of half the array is 2<sup>k</sup> / 2 = 2<sup>k-1</sup>
- The size of one quarter of the array is 2<sup>k</sup> / 4 = 2<sup>k-2</sup>
- ...

If you sum up all of these values, you get the following:

> 2<sup>k</sup> + 2<sup>k-1</sup> + 2<sup>k-2</sup> + ... + 2 + 1 = 2<sup>k+1</sup> - 1

You can prove this in several ways: you can use induction, or use the formula for the sum of a geometric series, etc.  This arises frequently in computer science, so it's worth committing to memory.

This means that if n = 2<sup>k</sup>, your algorithm runs in time

> 2<sup>k+1</sup> - 1 = 2(2<sup>k</sup>) - 1 = 2n - 1

So the runtime is 2n - 1, which is Θ(n).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the response, do you mind explaining a bit how you got 2^(k+1 )- 1 and that it runs in time 2n-1?

Comment: @Masterminder- I've just updated my answer to explain this.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes Thank you that helps a lot. So if I were to use like another type of searching like binary search to compare every element then how would that look like? I would still be performing it on a sorted array of length n and then an array of size n/2, etc. I know it runs in log(n) so would it look like something log(2^k) + log(2^(k-1))+... ?

Comment: @Masterminder- Exactly right.  And that simplifies down to k + (k - 1) + (k - 2) + ... + 2 + 1 = k(k + 1) / 2.  Since 2^k = n, this means that k = Theta(log n), so the overall runtime is Theta((log n)^2).

Comment: Just want to clarify to prove that result through geometric series :) (so i can see for myself). number of elements = n, a=2^k, r= 1/2?? Can you correct me if I am wrong. The formula to use would be a(1-r^n)/(1-r) since r is 0<r<1. I want to figure out how you go this 2^(k+1) -1

Comment: @Masterminder- You'd actually set a = 1, r = 2 and run the sum forward as 1 + 2 + ... + 2^n.  Try plugging those values in to the formula.